# Express routes when calling an external api

Tags: javascript, express

I'm using express to make a call to an external API

I want my homepage to be a search form, and then send a post request to `/results` where the route grabs the query from the search form, attaches it to the external API, makes the call, and then displays the results.

Keep in mind, the call is from [Google Graph Search API](https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/) and returns a JSON-LD

This is what I have so far:

```
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

// Set views
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

// Configure body-parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${PORT}!`);
});

const url =
  'https://www.example.com/api/search_wrapper?query=';

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req);
  res.render('search');
});

app.post('/results', (req, res) => {
  request(`${url}${req.body.term}`, (error, response, body) => {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      res.send(body);
      console.log(typeof body) // string
    } else {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
});
```

The above displays what looks like JSON, but when I try to send certain keys and when I console.log one, it comes as undefined. I'm guessing it's due to the fact that it's reading it as a string.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can try `JSON.parse(body)`. That should give you a javascript object with keys?

Comment: It's unclear what exactly your problem is.  You say in your code comments that `console.log(typeof body)` shows `string` so that's certainly not `undefined`.  What shows as `undefined`?  If it's in the client that you get `undefined`, then please show us the relevant client code.  I'd suggest you should also do `console.log(body)` and show us what that is.  You may also want to `console.log(req.body.term)` to see if that's what you're expecting too.  All-in-all, this question doesn't show what you've done yourself to debug and problem solve, thus we don't really know exactly where to help you.